# Strange “Undefined function” error in Matlab

Tags: matlab, bioinformatics, fasta

I met a problem with my Matlab code, that is when I try,

```
S1 = fastaread('saltA.fa');
```

It tells me that,
    Undefined function 'fastaread' for input arguments of type 'char'.

1. I am convinced that I used the function right.
2. I have `cd` into the folder where my file stores in Matlab.

It is just so weird, and from what I searched, there seems to be a lot more functions have such issue exists.

Comment: `fastaread.m` is not in working dir.

Comment: Do you have the Bioinformatics Toolbox?

Comment: Well I think fastaread is a official function? What should I do then.

Comment: What does `which fastaread` return in the Command Prompt?

Comment: /Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/toolbox/bioinfo/bioinfo/fastaread.m

Comment: Must I work under that directory?

Comment: Try running `rehash toolbox`

Comment: No you shouldn't have to.  MATLAB toolboxes are visible in any directory you are working from... that is the point of toolboxes.  Also for the sake of argument, try doing `clear fastaread`.

Comment: Those command doesn't work, I tried.

Comment: The only other reason is that I suspect your license to the toolbox is no longer valid. Try contacting your system administrator for support.

Answer (score -3):

fastaread might not in working directory or check the spellings

Comment: That's not the right answer. The function is part of the Bioinformatics toolbox. It should be visible regardless of what working directory you're in. You shouldn't HAVE to make sure it's in the working directory. You can verify that the OP has the toolbox in the comments stream above.